# Sprites/Icon Representation

Tags: buttons, icons, user-perception

I have an application and I'm currently working on the design at the minute.  As I have been working I've been thinking about little things to enhance the application.  One idea I thought about were the buttons.

Should Icons/Sprites be used to represent what buttons do?  Will these add more flavor and zest to the application?

Answer (score 1):

Icons have to be used with care. As the name implies, they need to be iconic, i.e., have some meaning to the user. There are very few buttons that have good icons; examples are Close or Save (even though nobody below the age of thirty has probably handled the floppy disk used in the conventional icon - I wonder when this will change to a cloud icon :-). This problem usually leads to the need that the user has to learn the icons used in your application. If he has motivation and time, that's ok.

Also, buttons with icon and text are quite full. And, if you have buttons which do not have conventional iconic representations, you either end up with bad icons or a mixture of buttons with and without icons.

Icons cannot be translated (well, you could use different icons sets for different locales, but I've never seen that done - any examples?).

Summing up, I'd use icons only if I was (or had support from) a good visual designer.

PS: The above applies only to "icons", not to decoration like gradients or animations.